# Ionic-react carousel with ionic slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

In Ionic-React how to create a carousel with ionic slides and want to use it inside the IonList, so the image can be a thumbnail or avatar. I tried changing the CSS but with no luck and also autoplay is not working.

Want to use it purely in ionic so that it can be accessed on mobile as well.

```
  const slideOptsOne = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: true
  };


        <IonList>
          <IonItem>
            <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOptsOne}>
              <IonSlide>
              <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                  <img src="image source" className="divSlide"/>
                  </IonThumbnail>
              </IonSlide>
              <IonSlide>
              <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                  <img src="image source" />
              </IonThumbnail>
              </IonSlide>
            </IonSlides>
            <IonLabel>
              <h5>Finn</h5>
              <h6>I'm a big deal</h6>
              <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
            </IonLabel>
            <IonLabel>
              <p>Finn</p>
              <p>I'm a big deal</p>
            </IonLabel>
          </IonItem>

          <IonItem>
            <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOptsOne}>
              <IonSlide>
              <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                  <img src="image source" className="divSlide"/>
                  </IonThumbnail>
              </IonSlide>
              <IonSlide>
              <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                  <img src="image source" />
              </IonThumbnail>
              </IonSlide>
            </IonSlides>
            <IonLabel>
              <h5>Han</h5>
              <h6>Look, kid...</h6>
              <p>I've got enough on my plate as it is, and I...</p>
            </IonLabel>
            <IonLabel>
              <p>Finn</p>
              <p>I'm a big deal</p>
            </IonLabel>
            <IonLabel>
              <h5>Han</h5>
              <h6>Look, kid...</h6>
              <p>I've got enough on my plate as it is, and I...</p>
            </IonLabel>
          </IonItem>
        </IonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The IonItem format is somewhat fixed. If you want to use it, I would suggest changing your approach to the following:

```
      <IonList>
          <IonItem>
            <IonThumbnail slot="start">
              <IonSlides options={slideOptsOne}>
                <IonSlide>
                  <IonImg alt="logo" src="..." />
                </IonSlide>
                <IonSlide>
                <IonImg alt="logo"  src="..." />
                </IonSlide>
              </IonSlides>
            </IonThumbnail>
            
            <IonLabel>
              <p>Finn</p>
              <p>I'm a big deal</p>
            </IonLabel>
          </IonItem>

          <IonItem>
            ...
          </IonItem>
        </IonList>
```